# Probability of drawing a ball

Tags: probability

A carton contains 12 red balls and 10 green balls. All same colored balls are identical. If we pick one ball at a time, look at it and do not return it to the box, until we have found all ten green balls, what is the probability that the tenth green ball is found in

i) the tenth trial,

ii) the twentieth trial?

I could solve (i). The probability for obtaining the 10th green ball in the 10th trial is $\frac{10*9*8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1}{22*21*20*19*18*17*16*15*14*13}$. This is obtained by multiplying the probability of obtaining a green ball in each trial.

I am stuck in (ii). I know that the first 19 trials should have 10 red balls and 9 green balls. So the total number of arrangements is $\frac{19!}{10!9!}$. How do I proceed from here?

Comment: I would say you are on the right track.  Calculate the number of ways those first 19 can be achieved.  Then with the remaining 3 balls, how many arrangements can you have where the green ball is first?  Multiply that by the first number.  And divide by the total number of ways to arrange the 22 balls.

Comment: So I am left with 1 green and 2 red balls. There is only 1 arrangement with the green ball being the first. The total arrangements of 22 balls is $\frac{22!}{12!10!}$. Thus the probability is $\frac{\frac{19!}{10!9!}}{\frac{22!}{12!10!}}$. Is this correct?

Comment: Actually, I might be off.  The way I was thinking about it is, 2 ways to arrange the final 3 with the green first, depending on the way the two reds were arranged.  I guess it depends on how you calculate the total number of arrangements.  I now have some reservations on my comment.

Comment: Yes, your last answer looks correct.

Comment: Yes, it is correct and actually 1/7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all note that we want that the 20th pick is a green ball. Otherwise we would have stopped before. Hence, we need to calculate the probability of finding 9 green balls in 19 picks and then multiply by $\frac{1}{3}$ (1 green ball out of 3 remaining balls = 2 red + 1 green). First, we want to calculate the former using the [Hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution):

Let $r$,$g$ be the number of red, green balls. Then the probability of finding the 9 green balls after 19 picks is $$P(g=9)=\frac{ {10 \choose 9} { {12} \choose {10}}} {22 \choose 19}.$$

Hence, the answer for ii) is 
$$P=\frac{1}{3}\frac{ {10 \choose 9} { {12} \choose {10}}} {22 \choose 19}=\frac 17.$$

Comment: Couldn't you have the first 9 green and then 10 red next?